# My Swift code is not calling deinit because of a closure strong reference or NSTimer. How can I solve it?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, memory-leaks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fadeBackground()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.fadeTime, target: self, selector: Selector("fadeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

func fadeBackground(){
    var spiralView: UIImageView?
    var subviews = self.view.subviews
    for v in subviews{
        if v.isKindOfClass(UIImageView){
            spiralView = v as? UIImageView
        }
    }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.fadeTime, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { [unowned self] () -> Void in
        var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme.count)))
        var randomIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme.count)))
        self.view.backgroundColor = CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme[randomIndex]
        if spiralView != nil {
            spiralView!.tintColor = CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme[randomIndex2]
        }
    }) { (stuff Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

As you can see, I already have `[unowned self]` in the closure.  I'm not sure why this view controller is still not calling deinit().  I guess there's still a memory leak somewhere?

Do I need to stop the timer on viewDidDisappear? How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Solved my question.

I had to invalidate my timer on viewWillDisappear.

```
var fader: NSTimer?
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    println("lobby viewWillDisappear")
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.fader!.invalidate()
    self.fader = nil
}
```

Comment: Better: `self.fader?.invalidate()`, otherwise it will crash if `fader` is `nil`.